# Socket.Accept() not working in Window Form c#

Tags: c#, sockets

I want to create an application client - server chat in LAN (Local Area Network). 
I demonstrate complete without error in Console c#. But when I use Window Form (c#), in Server side, it's stuck in the line:

```
Socket client = newsock.Accept();
```

and not running appear the Window Form.

How can I fix it? Thanks everybody!

Comment: please share more details code

Comment: @Mostafiz: The problem is crystal clear. "Accept()" is awaiting a request and for that reason the program freezes until that request is received.

Answer (score 0):

This is because, the `newsock.Accept()` method is actually awaiting a request and the next line of your code, which is apparently the initialization method for your UI component, is not reached until a request has been received. What you have to do is to move this into a thread and then assign it to the load event. For example:

```
public MyForm(){
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += OnWindowLoaded;
}  
private async void OnWindowLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() => {
        while (runState) {
             Socket client = newsock.Accept();
             // Then do the rest
        }
    });
}
```